# putting a swing component on another component without changing the layout from Free design to another?

Tags: java, swing, components

Can someone tell me how to put a java component on another component without changing the layout? I need to use Free Design because I want my program to be able to change its size according to the screen resolution.

What I expect by putting one component on another is that there is a jTextField and if someone is typing in it, I need to show a jTable under it to show suggestions. but there are another TextFields under it so currently I am unable to put a jTable or anything else. How can I do this?

Comment: *"I need to use Free Design because I want my program to be able to change its size according to the screen resolution."*  Many layouts can achieve that.  Oh, I see by [free design](http://www.formdev.com/jformdesigner/doc/layouts/grouplayout/) you actually mean `GroupLayout`.  Please don't speak Netbeans to us, we typically speak Java..

Comment: *"because I want my program to be able to change its size according to the screen resolution"* - This is what layout managers were designed to do...how ever...Free Form Layout isn't designed to be used by hand, it's designed to be used by the form designer...

Comment: @AndrewThompson Jinks and double jinks :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer  I think by 'free design' the OP actually means `GroupLayout`..

Comment: Thanks guys. and sorry about that. I'm totally new to this. but can one of explain me how to do it?

Comment: This use-case might be solved with a `JLayeredPane`.  See [How to Use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) for details and examples.

Answer (score 1):

Place your `JTable` with suggestion in a separate `JDialog` or `JWindow` and show it when necessary. Specify the `JDialog`/`JWindow` location based on the `JTextField`'s location on screen.